# How to locate the program that keeps mapping network drives to my computer?

Tags: windows-10, network-drive

I'm using a laptop with Windows 10 provided by the company. There might be some kind of script or program (probably schedule task) that keeps mapping two network drives as U: and X:, because when I disconnect them manually, they come back in minutes.
Is there any way to locate the program, so I can stop it? If no, can I hide all network drives from explorer?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use command prompt to map network drive in your mycomputer.
for example for `\\server_name\Documents` you must type in cmd:

```
net use Z: \\server_name\Documnets
```

If you use this mapped drive to persistent in your Computer must enter below command `Notic: Persistent is off by default`

```
net use Z: \\server_name\Documnets /persistent:Yes
```

And for delete this mapped drive Enter:

```
net use Z: /delete
```

You can this method in simpler way with create your own batch file to automated above procedure.

Comment: @KenZhang, Are you using `net use U: /delete` for  Drive `U:` and look at what happend? However, for last part of your question; Yes, you can with `registry` or `group policy`. For first part, you must look at startup script/application and disable it. OR look at Schedule with `schtasks` command to find which task run mapping network drive automatically, if you familiar with `command prompt`.